# Add a new subversion remote into existing Git repository

Tags: svn, git

I have a git repository fully tracking a remote SVN repo. Now I need to add a new branch that will be tracking a directory in a completely different SVN repo.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is. `git svn init` only edits the default svn remote, you'll have to edit the config file.

Look in `.git/config`, copy and alter the existing svn-remote section, and run `git svn fetch`. For example:

```
[svn-remote "svn2"]
        url = http://bzzz.googlecode.com/svn
        fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/svn2/trunk
        branches = branches/*:refs/remotes/svn2/*
        tags = tags/*:refs/remotes/svn2/tags/*
```

Comment: ```git svn fetch
[svn-remote "svn"] unknown```

Comment: @timger you can add the default svn remote by calling it `svn` not `svn2`, and you can do so with `git svn init`.  Reread the question to understand why I used `svn2` in my answer.