# How to import Subversion commits into Git upstream repository

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn

Here is my scenario:

- a *upstream* Git tag `1.2` has been used as first commit in an empty Subversion repository without `git svn`. Files have been copied and added into Subversion `trunk` working copy.
- in Subversion, a small list of changesets have been committed in `/trunk`

I now would like to use a Git fork from original *upstream* (large repository) and import these Subversion changesets into a *feature* branch created from initial tag `1.2`.

There is no branch or tag in Subversion repository I am interested in importing into *upstream* Git repository.

My first trial with `git-svn` was not successful because the branch created as no common ancestor with *upstream* history. How should I import my Subversion changesets to be able to operate merge in Git then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your take with using `git svn` is ok here.
You can either force the merge of unrelated histories with using `--allow-unrelated-histories` as parameter to the merge command.
Or you can just use `git cherry-pick` to reapply your newly imported commits on top of the Git tag.

Comment: Sorry histories are not unrelated... First Subversion commit matches exactly a tag in Git repository

Comment: Matches means IT is commit that was made by `git-svn`, or just that it has the same contents? If it is just the same contents, doesn't mean they are related histories. Unrelated history means that the two branches have no Git commit in common. Which is exactly the solution you described.

Comment: I agree. I have to test it also. By the way `git rebase` on imported branch seems to work either.

Comment: I consider your answer as the shortest path, because my original idea is probably too complex even if possible

Answer (score 0):

You can **migrate svn to git** by `git svn clone <URL for svn repo>` firstly. Then you can **merge the new converted git repo (assume master branch) into your upstream git repo master branch**. The merge steps as below:

```
# in your upstream git repo
git remote add new <path for the new converted git repo>
git fetch new
git checkout master
git rebase master new/master
git checkout -b temp
git checkout master
git merge temp
```

To solve the conflict files automatically when rebase, you can use `-X` options:

- Solve the conflict files with master version, `git rebase master new/master -X ours`.
- Solve the conflict files with new/master version, `git rebase master new/master -X theirs`.

Comment: Of course rebase introduce conflicts, I would like to resolve conflicts at latest step when merging subversion branch (changesets from a previous tag) into new master version

Comment: You can also solve the conflict automatically by `git rebase master new/master -X theirs`, this will keep the conflict files with `new/master` version. I added it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, here is a detailed procedure of what I did effectively. Idea is to first check potential conflicts from your custom code, before handling upgrade to latest.

1) Prepare your git repository. Inspired by: [Add a new subversion remote into existing Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367891/add-a-new-subversion-remote-into-existing-git-repository)

```
$ git clone UPSTREAM
```

Add a `git-svn` remote to repository in `.git/config`

```
[svn-remote "remote-trunk"]
    url = SUBVERSION_TRUNK_FOLDER_URL
    fetch = :refs/remotes/git-svn-remote-trunk
```

Run conversion into Git commits

```
$ git svn fetch --authors-prog=map_authors.sh remote-trunk
```

2) Rebase Subversion changesets on a `1.2` branch:

```
$ git branch custom-v1.2 v1.2
$ git checkout -b custom-trunk remotes/git-svn-remote-trunk
$ git rebase custom-v1.2
```

It is expected that first rebased commit is empty and must be confirmed with `git rebase --skip`.

In real life, I had end-of-line mismatch on few files I had to revert to original to avoid future conflicts.

After few `git rebase --continue` in case of conflicts to resolve, it is now possible to integrate custom code into latest master:

```
$ git checkout -b custom-master origin/master
$ git merge custom-trunk
```

*) An quicker alternative from [Vampire](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42574347/737790) is to directly merge either with tag-based branch or directly with latest `origin/master`

```
$ git checkout -b custom-v1.2 v1.2
$ git merge --allow-unrelated-histories remotes/git-svn-custom-trunk
$ git checkout -b custom-master origin/master
$ git merge custom-v1.2
```